# casting pointer to pointer... to pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers, casting

I found this snippet

```
void* operator new(size_t nbytes)
{
  if (nbytes == 0)
    nbytes = 1;                    // so all alloc's get a distinct address
  void* ans = malloc(nbytes + 4);  // overallocate by 4 bytes
  *(Pool**)ans = NULL;             // use NULL in the global new
  return (char*)ans + 4;           // don't let users see the Pool*
}
```

here https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/dtors

I spent over an hour now trying t understand what `*(Pool**)ans = NULL;` does.
`ans` is a void pointer, so I would assume it is cast to a `Pool` pointer and the pool is set to 0. Not he pointer but the pool itself, because of the third `*` on the left. But Pool has no `operator=` defined.

`pointer**` in a declaration is apparently a pointer to a pointer... but in this context this makes no sense to me, as `ans` is a single pointer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only reason to use `Pool**` here is semantic correctness, since presumably that "hidden" 4-byte header is supposed to be a pointer to a `Pool` (so `ans` is a pointer to a pointer to a `Pool`, and `*(Pool **)ans` has type `Pool *`).

You couldn't do `*(Pool *)ans = NULL` unless you were able to assign a `Pool` to `NULL`, and that is probably not the intended effect here anyways. Something like `*(int **)ans = NULL` or the more ridiculous `*(Pool ******)ans = NULL` would've had the same end effect but would have been semantically odd if it is ultimately intended to be a pointer to a `Pool`.

At the end of the day you'll end up with:

```
 +---+---+---+---+- - -
 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | ... and nbytes more bytes
 +---+---+---+---+- - -

 ^ ans           ^ returned address (ans + 4)
```

Where those first 4 bytes are intended to be a pointer to a `Pool` somewhere.

Another way to think about this is to ignore the whole `nbytes` thing, consider this general pattern:

```
void * ptr = malloc(sizeof(TYPE));
*(TYPE *)ptr = VALUE;
```

That should make sense. Now then if TYPE is a `Pool *` and VALUE is `NULL` and you fit it into that pattern, you can see how it all makes sense still:

```
void * ptr = malloc(sizeof(Pool *));
*(Pool **)ptr = NULL;
```

And then in your case you're still basically doing that although you're allocating some extra bytes at the end, but that's irrelevant to the types here.

As an aside, it's potentially asking for trouble here (and also semantically lazy) to hard-code `4` everywhere instead of `sizeof(Pool *)`.

Answer (score 3):

No, it is not "cast to a Pool pointer". The cast is a:

```
(Pool**)
```

This is not a pointer to a `Pool`. This is a pointer to a pointer to a `Pool`.

So, let's pretend now that `ans` is a `Pool **`, because that's what it is. In that case:

```
*ans = NULL;
```

This would now set the pointer that `ans` is pointer to, to a `NULL`. Not some manufactured instance of the `Pool` class. But a pointer to it.

But there's a bigger problem here:

```
 void* ans = malloc(nbytes + 4);  // overallocate by 4 bytes
 *(Pool**)ans = NULL;             // use NULL in the global new
 return (char*)ans + 4;           // don't let users see the Pool*
```

This is very old code, and it will work only if pointers are 4 bytes long.

On modern 64 bit platforms, with 8 byte-long pointers, this whole thing will fail miserably...

Comment: It is not "odd".  It is code that assumes all pointers to an object are 4-bytes (aka 32 bit, typically) and associated alignment.  The `4` would probably be better rewritten as `sizeof(Pool *)`.   Or remove it entirely - the offset is more of a dirty trick (a programmer trying to add a pseudo-safety measure), and doesn't achieve much of real use.   (If removing it, also modify other functions that directly manipulate the `Pool`, as they will also use the offset).

Comment: @Peter Sam typed "OLD" not "ODD".